# Server Error 500 when renaming system folder in EE3

Tags: ee3, system

On EE2 we rename the system folder, and then update index.php and our renamed admin.php. We attempted to do so in EE3, following the instructions here (which is the same as EE2) https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/installation/best_practices.html.

But once we do this we get an Server Error 500. There are no errors in the log for this.

The instructions do state they may be other areas in the CP to change it, but we cant access the CP. There is no record of "system" in the database.

**index.php**

```
$system_path = './system3WmKw98f';
```

**admin.php**

```
$system_path = './system3WmKw98f';
```

**Folder name**

```
public_html/system3WmKw98f
```

Does anyone know what the issue is?

If I set the folder to system, at least i get the following error "Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php"

Also, there is no .htaccess with my EE install, dont know if its relevant.

Comment: Hi Laurence, did you ever figure out the issue with this and or a resolve?  I'm having a similar issue however I get a 500 server error: "The ... page isn’t working ... is currently unable to handle this request. 500

Comment: Sorry not yet! But I haven't spent time on this since.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to put the system folder above webroot, so its absolutely not accessible for the public. renaming then, is not needed anymore. our EE setup looks like:

- public html

  - index.php
- system

in index.php we set system directory like:

`` $system_path = __DIR__ . '/../system';` ``

maybe that helps.